# How to test an npm module that requires DOM elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, module

I am currently new to developing npm modules and trying to develop my first one. I would like to be able to include it in the browser (with a script tag) as well as make it available via npm install ... and I would also like to be able to test it, both by opening a html page in the browser with the code included and by running tests via Node (with npm run test, for example).

Basically, my library plots x, y graphs on a canvas based on the id of the canvas so I would use it like:

```
var g1 = new Plotter('canvas1');
g1.plot([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]];
```

So my Plotter constructor looks like this

```
constructor(idElement) {
    this.canvas = root.document.getElementById(idElement);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.origin = {
        x: this.canvas.width / 2,
        y: this.canvas.height / 2
    };
}
```

It works well in the browser but trying Mocha, Chai, AVA, Jasmine, I could not figure out how to run tests. It always results in **cannot find property  getElementById of undefined**. Here is my constructor test:

```
it('Constructor test', function() {
        const window = new Window();
        const canvas = window.document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas1');
        const g1 = new Plotter('canvas1');
        g1.plot([0,0],[40,5]);
        expect(canvas.id).to.equal('graphique');
    });
```

Do you know a way how I am supposed to do this or if at all, it is good practice to use getELementById in a npm module? Should I just receive width and height of the canvas as arguments of the constructor instead?

Let me know if you need more information,

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre looping for fixtures, litlle pieces of code that can (temporary) mock/stub HTML for testing. You can use a Library like jasmine-jquery for this (even if you’re not usibg jquery).

I build an NPM module for DOM manipulation ([bem.js](https://github.com/maykinmedia/bem.js)) wich is also tested using this method. You might be able to use it as reference.

Comment: Hello Sven, is bem.js usable in browser? (with the script tag). But yes, jasmine-jquery could do the job, I will have to look more deeply into your code and see if I canfit it with what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Node does not have a DOM or window object, so you won't be able to test canvas libraries in Node,

[NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) combines a web-kit browser with all of node.js functionality and may suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you traktor53, I will look into NW.js!